# Calculate the SUM() time from columns with mixed types

Tags: openoffice-calc

Consider the following table:

```
+------------------+------+--------+
|     Total worked | Total|  Tasks |
+------------------+------+--------+
|             07:30| 09:20|Day 10  |
+-----+-----+------+------+--------+
|09:00|09:20| 00:20| Task1         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|09:20|09:25|'00:05| Task2         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|09:25|09:30|'00:05| Task3         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|09:30|10:30|'01:00| Task4         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|10:30|13:00| 02:30| Task5         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|15:00|19:40| 04:40| Task6         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
|19:40|20:20|'00:40| Task7         |
+-----+-----+------+---------------+
```

(I'm really sorry, but couldn't do better).

The `Total Worked` is how much I've worked in a single day.
The values are calculated with 2 formules:

- Ignored times (in the table, times starting with `'`):
  `=TEXT(Bxx-Axx+ STYLE("CustomDoNotCalc");"hh:mm" )`
- Calculated times:
  `=Bxx-Axx`

The `Total Worked` is calculated with a simple `=SUM(Cxx:Cxx)`.

The `Total` is introduced manually.

I want it to be calculated instead of being manual.

I've tried the following formules with the following results:

- `=SUM(DATE.VALUE(Cxx:Cxx))` - Error `#VALUE?` and `#VALUE!`
- `=SUM(DATE.VALUE(TEXT(Cxx:Cxx,'hh:mm')))` - Error `#VALUE?`
- Another one, but I forgot which

What can I do to calculate the `Total` time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a helper column, you may use a [array formula](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays):

> `=SUM(C2:C8,(IF(ISERROR(TIMEVALUE(C2:C8)),0,TIMEVALUE(C2:C8))))`

The result looks as follows:

[image]

To enter the array formula in C9, enter the formula above **without the curly braces** `{}`, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. OO Calc will display the formula inside curly braces to indicate it's an array formula.

Comment: OH BOY! Nice one! It works like a treat! The right formule for OpenOffice Calc is `=SUM(Cxx:Cxx;(IF(IS.ERROR(HOUR.VALUE(Cxx:Cxx));0;HOUR.VALUE(Cxx:Cxx))))`. I wasn't able to use this as an array formule though the keyboard shortcut, but checking the box under the formule navigation had the desired effect. Thank you!

Comment: The only 'quirk' is that the formula won't be calculated as an array when copy-pasted. Other than that, it works perfectly!

Comment: Hmm - i think copy-paste should work, but instead of "leaving" the input line using the `Enter` key, [you'll have to use the combination CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Array_formulas). Maybe it's a matter of localisation which combination of keys to use to enter an array formula? But i'm very happy to hear that you found a way to make it work for you!

Comment: I think it is a bug on the keyboard (it has a MASSIVE delay). It really should work but I have no idea why it doesn't. But anyway, thank you for your huge help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to introduce a **helper column** indicating if the time should be considered when calculating "Total worked". This way, it's quite easy to calculate the durations using SUM() and [**`SUMIF()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function):

[image]

Column C (Duration) is simply `=Bx-Ax`. "Total worked (C9)" is `=SUM(C2:C8)`, and "Net worked (C19)" is `=SUMIF(D2:D8,"=1",C2:C8)`.  Cell Format for all cells is `HH:MM`. I've added some conditional formatting to highlight the tasks recognized for net working time.

*(created with LibreOffice, should be the same with OpenOffice Calc)*

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Sadly, I already have over 150 rows filled. But nothing serious. What I could also try it to set a negative time, if that is even possible. I will try to find something usable. Thank you for that tip.